# Can i use HTML instead of echo in IF-ELSE statement in PHP?

Tags: php, html, echo

```
if( $user->username == 'XYZ' )
{ 
echo "hello, XYZ";
}
else
{
echo "hello, guest";
}
```

In the above code, can i use pure html code which will get executed incase the **IF statement is true** instead of using **echo** ?

Comment: @vlzvl-How can you add `<br>` ?

Comment: @Subhanker, in the HTML? just type `<br>` when you're outside of `<php ?>` tags.

Comment: @vlzvl-well I am well aware of it but my point was, your edit was invalid and that too was inside `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it:

```
if( $user->username == 'XYZ' ) 
{
?>
hello, XYZ
<?
} 
else
{
?>
hello, guest
<?
}
```

Sometimes it looks better and simplier. But in fact it is much better to put php and html code in different files (separate logic, styles and data).

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $user->username == 'XYZ' )
{ ?>
<p>Hello <b><i>XYZ</i></b>
<?php }

else { ?>
<p>Hello <b><i>Guest</i></b>
<?php 
}
```

I hope You Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can write HTML directly by closing the `<?php ?>` tags.

```
<?php if( $user->username == 'XYZ') { ?>
   hello, XYZ<br>
<?php } ?>
<?php else { ?>
   hello, guest<br>
<?php } ?>
```

You can of course heredoc as well:

```
<?php
   $str = <<<FOO
This is a
demo message
FOO;

echo $str;
?>
```

but i dont use it since i it messes with any highlighting editor (it thinks it's a text and i like my HTML highlighted)

What i like best is this, especially when my outputs are big:

```
<?php if( $user->username == 'XYZ') {
   include("user_template.php");
}
<?php else { ?>
   include("guest_template.php");
<?php } ?>
```

which are actually just rendering HTML contained there.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be written like this, more readable for several lines.

```
<?php if ($user->username == 'XYZ') : ?>
    Hello, XYZ
<?php else : ?>
    Hello, Guest
<?php endif; ?>
```